# Electronic symboles in datasheets

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, telecommunication, electrical

I found these symbols in a electronic datasheet.. Are these all logic gates? or another?
[image: What does this symbols mean?]

Comment: Can you please post the datasheet that your referencing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! The logic gates from a RS485/422. Most likely the signal are level shifted. Below is an except form [Low power RS-485/RS-422 transceiver ST485B, ST485C](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/st485b.pdf) datasheet.

[image]

Below is an another similar part. [PROFIBUS Compliant 6kV VDE-Reinforced Isolated RS-485 Transceiver ISL32741E](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/isl32741e.pdf). The example circuit is converting signal 3.3V-5V and 5V-3.3V.

[image]